# annotation jpa hibernate

Tags: jpa

in my class request.java I have attribute logo

logo is an image that will record in the mysql database

I am looking for the annotation required attribute logo

I try with

```
@ Lob
private String logo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you do not want to persist image with character data type.

For `BLOB` type in database `byte[]` is correct Java type:

```
@Lob
private byte[] logo;
```